# Any benefit of using yield in this case?

Tags: c#, yield-return

I am maintaining some code at work and the original author is gone so thought I would ask here to see if I can satisfy my curiosity.

Below is a bit of code (anonymized) where yield is being used.  As far as I can tell it does not add any benefit and just returning a list would be sufficient, maybe more readable as well (for me at least).  Just wondering if I am missing something because this pattern is repeated in a couple of places in the code base.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<string> ValidProductTypes
{
  get
  {
    yield return ProductTypes.Type1;
    yield return ProductTypes.Type2;
    yield return ProductTypes.Type3;
  }
}
```

This property is used as a parameter for some class which just uses it to populate a collection:

```
var productManager = new ProductManager(ValidProductTypes);

public ProductManager(IEnumerable<string> validProductTypes)
{
  var myFilteredList = GetFilteredTypes(validProductTypes);
}

public ObservableCollection<ValidType> GetFilteredTypes(IEnumerable<string> validProductTypes)
{
  var filteredList = validProductTypes
                    .Where(type => TypeIsValid); //TypeIsValid returns a ValidType
  return new ObservableCollection<ValidType>(filteredList);
}
```

Comment: A benefit could be, although it doesn't seem to be in this case, that when the enumeration isn't completed, for example with a FirstOrDefault, not all potential costly executions are executed for the later yields, which would have been for a list. In this case, if Type2 was a heavy property, but the enumeration doesn't consume it, it would be lighter than a list.

Comment: IMHO, that scenario is better implemented with a simple array. I don't feel the iterator method syntax adds anything. But that's primarily a matter of opinion. You don't seem to have any actual, practical programming _problem_ to solve here.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that returning an `IEnumerable<T>` and implementing that using `yield return` is the *simplest* option.

If you see that a method returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, there really is only one thing you can do with it: iterate it. Any more complicated operations on it (like using LINQ) are just encapsulated specific ways of iterating it.

If a method returns an array or list, you also gain the ability to mutate it and you might start wondering if that's an acceptable use of the API. For example, what happens if you do `ValidProductTypes.Add("a new product")`?

If you're talking just about the implementation, then the difference becomes much smaller. But the caller would still be able to cast the returned array or list from `IEnumerable<T>` to its concrete type and mutate that. The chance that anyone would actually think this was the intended use of the API is small, but with `yield return`, the chance is zero, because it's not possible.

Considering that I'd say the syntax has roughly the same complexity and ease of understanding, I think `yield return` is a reasonable choice. Though with C# 6.0 expression bodied properties, the syntax for arrays might get the upper hand:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<string> ValidProductTypes =>
  new[] { ProductTypes.Type1, ProductTypes.Type2, ProductTypes.Type3 };
```

---

The above answer is assuming that this is not performance-critical code, so fairly small differences in performance won't matter. If this is performance-critical code, then you should measure which option is better. And you might also want to consider getting rid of allocations (probably by caching the array in a field, or something like that), which might be the dominant factor.

Comment: While looking simple, I would expect those `yield return` usages, which effectively turn the thing into a generator, to result in far more complicated IL under the hood than using an enumerable collection. I would assume that this would have performance implications too (not critical, but likely different to e.g. a plain array).